# Need to calculate progression with array

Tags: c, arrays

I have following task:

Calculate `x1 + x2 + .... + x20`, if the sequence `x1, x2, ... xn` is awarded to the following rule: `x1 = 1, x2 = 0.3, x(i) = (i +1) * x(i-2), i = 3,4 ..`

Can someone help to make this task? I don't know how to begin write progression...
I have tried writing this:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    double X[20];
    for (i=3; i<=19; i++){
        X[i]=(i+1)*X[i-2];
    }

    for (i=0; i<=19; i++)
        printf("%7d%13d\n", i, X[i]);

    system ("pause");
}
```

Comment: You should probably assign values for the first two before your loop. Also, should your loop go from 2 to 19 rather than 3? This looks a bit like C/C++ rather than C# too. Do you have the correct tags?

Comment: I assigned values by writing:
    
`X[1]=1;
     X[2]=0.3;`  
It is correct form or not? I don't understand arrays very good, and how to work with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at your current code :

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    double X[20];
    for (i=3; i<=19; i++){
        X[i]=(i+1)*X[i-2];
    }

    for (i=0; i<=19; i++)
        printf("%7d%13d\n", i, X[i]);

    system ("pause");
}
```

Don't forget that when you declare array in C, indices begin at 0 and not 1. Then, `x1 = 1, x2 = 0.3` will be interpret as : `X[0] = 1;` and `X[1] = 0.3;`.

Next, `x(i) = (i +1) * x(i-2), i = 3,4 ..` will be interpret as :

```
for (i=2; i<=19; i++){
    X[i]=(i+2) * X[i-2];
}
```

Now, you want to sum the `xi` for i = 1,...,20. Then, your code will be something like this :

```
int main()
{
    double X[20];

    // First two elements of your serie.
    X[0] = 1;
    printf("%7d%13f\n", 1, X[0]);
    X[1] = 0.3;
    double result = X[0] + X[1];
    printf("%7d%13f\n", 2, X[1]);

    // Third element to the 20th element of your serie.
    for (int i=2; i<=19; i++){
        X[i]=(i+2)*X[i-2];
        printf("%7d%13f\n", i+1, X[i]);
        result += X[i];
    }

    printf("\nSum of xi = %f", result);

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This will keep track of `X[i]`, iteration `i` and the final result. You'll then get all information you need. Also, [this C arrays tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm) may help you to understand arrays.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Strange, but your codes not working correctly or I don't understand. I'am getting wrong answers.

Comment: @SiRaZz I forgot about `%f` in the `printf`. Instead of `printf("%7d%13d\n", i, X[i]);`, it's `printf("%7d%13f\n", i, X[i]);` because `X[i]` is a double, not an integer. Thanks to tell me. This should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is almost correct with some modifications, try this :

```
int main(void) {

    int i;
    double result = 1.3;
    double X[20];
    X[0] = 1;
    X[1] = 0.3;

    for (i=2; i<=19; i++){
       X[i]=(i+2)*X[i-2];
       result += X[i];
    }

    printf("%f", result);
    system ("pause");


   return 0;
}
```

The reason I put `(i+2)` instead of `(i+1)` is because the array is zero-based.

Answer (score 0):

As a reminder, you want: `x1 = 1, x2 = 0.3, x(i) = (i +1) * x(i-2)` for every value of `i` in [1,20].

It is not necessary to store everything in order to compute the sum but that's your choice. So Start by creating the array:

```
double X[21]; // 21 because you start from 1 and not 0.
```

Then init the first 2 values:

```
X[1] = 1;
X[2] = 0.3;
```

Now you can use your loop (but up to 20):

```
for (i=3; i<=20; i++){
    X[i]=(i+1)*X[i-2];
}
```

And you can also compute the sum:

```
double sum = X[1] + X[2];
for (i=3; i<=20; i++){
    X[i]=(i+1)*X[i-2];
    sum += X[i];
}
```

Now, I said it was not necessary to store every value, to be more precise, you can only store the last 2 values. I'll let you do that as an exercise (and I think it's a good exercise).